# PowerShell Script does not generate an error, but is not working correctly

Tags: function, powershell, scripting

I just want to write a basic PowerShell script which compares two numbers. When I call my script via `.\Compare-Numbers.ps1 -a 3 -b 3` nothing happens.

```
function Compare-Numbers {

    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, HelpMessage="Please enter two numbers")]
    [int]$a, 
    [int]$b
    )

    try {
        if($a -eq $b) {
            Write-Host "the given numbers are equal"
            return (exit 0)
        }
        else {
            Write-Host "the given numbers are not equal"
            return (exit 1)
        }
    }
    catch {
        throw "an error occured!"
        exit $LASTEXITCODE
    }
}
```

I would expect that the write-host command writes the text in my command prompt, but - nothing happens.

Comment: The main reason is you're setting the function, you'd need to the call the function `compare-numbers` though i'd be interested as to know why your code isn't correctly working - when I'm running it it's refusing to ask for `$b` for me and I'm unsure why.

Comment: The `return (exit 1)` will throw an error because `exit` is not known. Replace `throw "an error occured!"` with `throw $_` to see the error.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you're a little confused. You created a function and saved it to a file. If you run the file, PowerShell will say:

> yep, function loaded, nothing else to do, bye!

If you plan to run this from a file, you will need to change your approach a little. [This article](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/how-do-i-use-a-windows-powershell-script-containing-functions/) perfectly describes your current situation and issue.

This is what your script would end up looking like:

```
Param($intOne = 5,
$intTwo = 3
)
Function add-numbers
{
Param($intOne,
$intTwo
)
$intOne + $intTwo
} #end function add-numbers
# *** entry point to script ***
add-numbers -intOne $intOne -inttwo $intTwo
```

Comment: thank you really much, the artivel was exactly what i needed and now my script does what it should do

Answer (score 1):

A Bit of a late reply but I was interested in your code and wanted to correct the value prompting:

```
function Number-comparison {

    param(
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, HelpMessage="text")][int]$a1,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$True, HelpMessage="text")][int]$b1

    )
```

If we use the above it will prompt the user correctly.